# Why VS and other IDEs uses the Windows Basic theme?

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio, mdi

I have a little question to ask here. I've not found any answers anywhere.
Why in Visual Studio and the other IDEs, in the form designer, it uses the Windows Basic theme and not the current theme, Aero or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, MDI has been deprecated for many years (at least on Windows), so the theme used is the theme that was current when MDI was still a viable design choice.

If you're developing new software, the Windows guidelines suggest using other alternative approaches instead of MDI.